Downloading CSV file from Google Earth Engine
I am having difficulties downloading the CSV file. The code which I was using was this
// Load Pakistan boundary
var pakistan = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level0')
                 .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Pakistan'));   
// Define mangrove areas using a known mangrove dataset
var mangroves = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/assets/pk-mangroves');

// Center the map on Pakistan
Map.centerObject(pakistan, 6);
var s1Collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                      .filterBounds(mangroves) // Filter by mangrove area
                      .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2024-12-31') // Filter date range
                      .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW')) // Filter by Sentinel-1 IW mode
                      .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV')) // VV polarization
                      .select('VV'); // Select only the VV band

// Print size to see if the collection has images
print('Sentinel-1 Image Count:', s1Collection.size());

// Calculate mean backscatter from the filtered Sentinel-1 ImageCollection
var meanBackscatter = s1Collection.mean();
// Print the result to see if it's valid
print('Mean Backscatter:', meanBackscatter);

// Classify mangroves based on backscatter threshold
var threshold = -15; // Define the backscatter threshold (adjust as needed)
var mangrovesClassified = meanBackscatter.lt(threshold); 

// Pixels with backscatter less than the threshold are classified as mangroves
// Print classified mangroves
print('Mangroves Classified:', mangrovesClassified);

// Mask non-mangrove areas (binary mask)
var mangroveMask = mangrovesClassified.updateMask(mangrovesClassified);

// Visualize the mean backscatter
Map.centerObject(mangroves, 8); // Center the map to the mangrove region
Map.addLayer(meanBackscatter, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'Mean Backscatter');

// Visualize classified mangroves
Map.addLayer(mangroveMask, {palette: 'green'}, 'Mangrove Mask');

// Function to classify mangroves for a given year
function classifyYear(year) {
  var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
  var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 12, 31);
 var s1Year = s1Collection.filterDate(start, end);
  var meanBackscatterYear = s1Year.mean();
  var mangroveClassifiedYear = meanBackscatterYear.lt(threshold);
  var mangroveMaskYear = mangroveClassifiedYear.updateMask(mangroveClassifiedYear);
  
  return mangroveMaskYear.set('year', year);
}
// Map over years
var years = ee.List.sequence(2014, 2024);
var yearlyMangroves = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(year){
    return classifyYear(year);
  })
);
// Display mangrove extent for each year
var mangrovePalette = ['white', 'green'];
var yearsList = years.getInfo();

yearsList.forEach(function(year) {
  var image = yearlyMangroves.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', year)).first();
  Map.addLayer(image, {palette: mangrovePalette}, 'Mangroves ' + year.toString());
});

// Chart the total mangrove area over time
var areaList = years.map(function(year){
  var image = yearlyMangroves.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', year)).first();
  var pixelArea = image.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
  var stats = pixelArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: mangroves.geometry(),
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  var area = stats.get('constant');
  return ee.Feature(null, {'year': year, 'area': area});
});
var areaChart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(ee.FeatureCollection(areaList), 'year', 'area')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Mangrove Area Over Time',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Area (sq meters)'}
  });

print(areaChart);

// Export the mangrove extent for the latest year with optimized parameters
var latestYearImage = yearlyMangroves.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', 2024)).first();

// Ensure the region is a bounded rectangle to avoid excessive data
var exportRegion = mangroves.geometry().bounds();

// Export the latest year mangrove extent image
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: latestYearImage,
  description: 'Mangroves_2024',
  scale: 30, // Adjust scale to balance resolution and file size
  region: exportRegion, // Use bounded geometry for better performance
  maxPixels: 1e9 // Reduce maxPixels if needed to comply with size limits
});

// Export the area statistics as a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(areaList),
  description: 'MangroveAreaOverTime',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site. In order for us to help, you need to describe the exact nature of the problem. It is not enough to state that you are "having difficulties", since that could mean anything. Please [Edit] the Question.

The assest projects/assets/pk-mangroves is not public can you please share that asset or change that to geometry, so we can reproduce the issue ? Also can you please add what is the error ?

The stats computed from ee.Image.reduceRegion will be stored with the name of the band of image. As band name is VV have to use VV instant of constant to access the value. The csv file will be exported using the following code.
// Load Pakistan boundary
var pakistan = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level0')
                 .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Pakistan'));

// Define mangrove areas using a known mangrove dataset
// var mangroves = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/assets/pk-mangroves');
// Using extents as above asset is not public
var mangroves = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [
    [67.01, 24.80],
    [67.02, 24.80],
    [67.02, 24.85],
    [67.01, 24.85],
    [67.01, 24.80]
  ]
]));
// Center the map on Pakistan
Map.centerObject(pakistan, 6);
var s1Collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                      .filterBounds(mangroves) // Filter by mangrove area
                      .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2024-12-31') // Filter date range
                      .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW')) // Filter by Sentinel-1 IW mode
                      .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV')) // VV polarization
                      .select('VV'); // Select only the VV band

// Check if the collection has images
print('Sentinel-1 Image Count:', s1Collection.size());

// Calculate mean backscatter from the filtered Sentinel-1 ImageCollection
var meanBackscatter = s1Collection.mean();
// Print the result to see if it's valid
print('Mean Backscatter:', meanBackscatter);

// Classify mangroves based on backscatter threshold
var threshold = -15; // Define the backscatter threshold (adjust as needed)
var mangrovesClassified = meanBackscatter.lt(threshold); 

// Pixels with backscatter less than the threshold are classified as mangroves
// Print classified mangroves
print('Mangroves Classified:', mangrovesClassified);

// Mask non-mangrove areas (binary mask)
var mangroveMask = mangrovesClassified.updateMask(mangrovesClassified);

// Visualize the mean backscatter
Map.centerObject(mangroves, 8); // Center the map to the mangrove region
Map.addLayer(meanBackscatter, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'Mean Backscatter');

// Visualize classified mangroves
Map.addLayer(mangroveMask, {palette: 'green'}, 'Mangrove Mask');

// Function to classify mangroves for a given year
function classifyYear(year) {
  var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
  var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 12, 31);
 var s1Year = s1Collection.filterDate(start, end);
  var meanBackscatterYear = s1Year.mean();
  var mangroveClassifiedYear = meanBackscatterYear.lt(threshold);
  var mangroveMaskYear = mangroveClassifiedYear.updateMask(mangroveClassifiedYear);
  
  return mangroveMaskYear.set('year', year);
}
// Map over years
var years = ee.List.sequence(2014, 2024);
var yearlyMangroves = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(year){
    return classifyYear(year);
  })
);
// Display mangrove extent for each year
var mangrovePalette = ['white', 'green'];
var yearsList = years.getInfo();

yearsList.forEach(function(year) {
  var image = yearlyMangroves.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', year)).first();
  Map.addLayer(image, {palette: mangrovePalette}, 'Mangroves ' + year.toString());
});

// Chart the total mangrove area over time
var areaList = years.map(function(year){
  var image = yearlyMangroves.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', year)).first();
  var pixelArea = image.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
  var stats = pixelArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: mangroves.geometry(),
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  var area = stats.get('VV'); // It has to name of the band
  return ee.Feature(null, {'year': year, 'area': area});
});
print(areaList);

  
var areaChart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(ee.FeatureCollection(areaList), 'year', 'area')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Mangrove Area Over Time',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Area (sq meters)'}
  });

print(areaChart);

// Export the mangrove extent for the latest year with optimized parameters
var latestYearImage = yearlyMangroves.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', 2024)).first();

// Ensure the region is a bounded rectangle to avoid excessive data
var exportRegion = mangroves.geometry().bounds();

// Export the latest year mangrove extent image
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: latestYearImage,
  description: 'Mangroves_2024',
  scale: 30, // Adjust scale to balance resolution and file size
  region: exportRegion, // Use bounded geometry for better performance
  maxPixels: 1e9 // Reduce maxPixels if needed to comply with size limits
});

// Export the area statistics as a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(areaList),
  description: 'MangroveAreaOverTime',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

The same code can be found here.
Please note that as projects/assets/pk-mangroves is not public I have defined the polygon as using four corner coordinates.
